# How to get rounded borders in dropdown menu of weglot plugin in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

i'm using weglot plugin in my wordpress site ! i want to get the language button as a rounded border dropdown menu 
the problem is when i use border-radius and overflow hidden i can't see my select items ? and when i remove overflow i get the 90° border of the the select as a background

[With overflow hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEOlL.png)

[without overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx13v.png)

[The source code of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4FgJ.png)

```
.country-selector{

border-radius:36px;

  display:inline-block;

  overflow:hidden;

  background:#cccccc;

  border:4px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: show more of your code (css and html)

Comment: You need to share your markup (html and css)

Comment: please add the css to the dropdown list, also the html would help a lot

Comment: in fact i'm using poopy life , installed weglot plugin and use default theme so i can't access to html pages i have control on welgot 's main configuration page which offer you to write an additional css to their pre-made button